# Libpurple not working from bash

Tags: linux, bash, libpurple

I'm using accessing thorough DBUS from some process. The trouble is that it runs from another user and session of DBUS is different for them. So I can't acces application which uses DBUS through another process if the sessions are different. I found the way to resolve this trouble: some script writes into file dbus session data from main user (I set it at system loading). Here is that script:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /.Xdbus
chmod 666 /.Xdbus
env | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > /.Xdbus
echo 'export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS' >> /.Xdbus
```

Here is an example of that file:

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-9yStbCgjwb,guid=0deadb6519676638e1e93f5000000023
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

Now I just have to execute data from that file and both DBUS sessions will be same. Here is some troubles:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /.Xdbus ]
then
    source /.Xdbus; /usr/bin/purple-remote "setstatus?status=away&message=At lunch"
else
    echo "File doesnt exist"
fi
```

As you could see, I'm using pidgin as DBUS application. But it throws the error, that there is no purple application, so the DBUS sessions are different! So comand:

```
source /.Xdbus
```

Didn't work. Why?

---

**UPD**

```
source /.Xdbus; echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS; /usr/bin/purple-remote "setstatus?status=away&message=At lunch"; echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS;
```

→

```
unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-9yStbCgjwb,guid=0deadb6519676638e1e93f5000000023 No existing libpurple instance detected. unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-9yStbCgjwb,guid=0deadb6519676638e1e93f5000000023
```

Comment: Didn't it? What do you see if you "echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" right after sourcing /.Xdbus? Or "cat /.Xdbus" right before sourcing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update, the `source` command is working. Therefore the problem is with `purple-remote` or `libpurple` or some dependency rather than with your Bash script.

It's not a good idea to create such files in the root directory. Try choosing a more appropriate location for your file. One of the following perhaps:

- `/home/username/.Xdbus`
- `/var/local/.Xdbus` - you might have to add your user to the group that owns this directory
- `/tmp/.Xdbus`

Comment: Hm, I moved it to the /tmp/.Xdbus and now there aren't any errors but status doesn't change.

Comment: @Ockonal: Apparently it's now working? What else did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you use / which is the root of the filesystem.
What you want is ./ or an absolute path as said Dennis.

You can also use $PWD/file or ${pwd}/file

Comment: with $PWD/.Xdbus it says that file doesn't exist. But with /tmp/.Xdbus there aren't errors. But status is the same.

Comment: depends from where you run the script. If possible, prefer an absolute path.

Comment: Script is in /bin/script.sh with need rights `-rwxr--r-- 1 root root `

Comment: Hm, now it won't work even If I run it from console from default user. It worked before. So strange.